# Create 'pop' object by demography package correctly

Tags: r

I have to create demogdata object based on my data. ‘Fert’ and ‘Mort’ objects – rates, exposure – are all clear. But concerning the ‘Pop’ object. I understand it must be population as of Jan 01, not exposure (actually I checked it by comparing raw data from HMD txt files and Hyndman’s original ‘pop2010’ object). But what an argument must I put instead of ‘rates’?
What I have tried:
1. put an argument ‘skip’:
`dnipop <- read.demogdata(file=skip, "pop.txt", )`
It’s does not work.
2. put the same data as pop (sort of dummy variable):
`dnipop <- read.demogdata("pop.txt", "pop.txt", )`
Actually, it’s work seamlessly. I managed even to walk through to the completed forecast. But still, I’m curious how to do it correct, without 'rates' element.
Example you can find here
[enter link description here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/coherent-population-forecasting/)
I other words, Hyndman's object has structure:

```
> str(pop2010)
List of 6
 $ type  : chr "population"
 $ label : chr "Australia"
 $ lambda: num 0
 $ year  : int [1:97] 1921 1922 1923 1924 1925 1926 1927 1928 1929 1930 ...
 $ age   : num [1:101] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ pop   :List of 3
  ..$ female: num [1:101, 1:97] 62848 57777 56941 58272 58719 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:97] "1921" "1922" "1923" "1924" ...
  ..$ male  : num [1:101, 1:97] 65851 60217 59047 60218 60773 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:97] "1921" "1922" "1923" "1924" ...
  ..$ total : num [1:101, 1:97] 128699 117994 115988 118490 119492 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:97] "1921" "1922" "1923" "1924" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "demogdata"
```

But my object has structure:

```
> str(dnipop)
List of 7
 $ type  : chr "population"
 $ label : chr "Dnipro"
 $ lambda: num 0
 $ year  : int [1:18] 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 ...
 $ age   : num [1:101] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ rate  :List of 3
  ..$ female: num [1:101, 1:18] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:18] "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" ...
  ..$ male  : num [1:101, 1:18] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:18] "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" ...
  ..$ total : num [1:101, 1:18] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:18] "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" ...
 $ pop   :List of 3
  ..$ female: int [1:101, 1:18] 3243 3170 3215 3363 3411 3687 3910 4103 4372 4914 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:18] "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" ...
  ..$ male  : int [1:101, 1:18] 3392 3407 3423 3451 3734 3959 4278 4201 4783 5370 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:18] "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" ...
  ..$ total : int [1:101, 1:18] 6635 6577 6638 6814 7145 7646 8188 8304 9155 10284 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:18] "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "demogdata"
```

You can see the 'dummy' element $rate which is not present in Hyndman's object.
Thank you! Sorry for many words, it's my first question.

How to get rid of this part in my object:

```
 $ rate  :List of 3
  ..$ female: num [1:101, 1:18] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:18] "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" ...
  ..$ male  : num [1:101, 1:18] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:18] "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" ...
  ..$ total : num [1:101, 1:18] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "0" "1" "2" "3" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:18] "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" ...
```

Comment: Hi Pavlo, I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. Do you mean `pop2010` (default data) works as it is expected to and `dnipop` (your data) doesn't work? Which set  of commands would you like to be run on `dnipop` ?

Comment: I`d like to get rid of this part in my object  $ rate  :List of 3
 
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 up to $ pop

Comment: Can you try this? `new_pop <- dnipop[names(dnipop) != 'rate']`

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I did not even tried != operator. Wonderful! Thank a lot! Problem solved.

Comment: Thanks, Ronak. I'm new at Stack Overflow and R, you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove the `"rate"` list by name using `!=` operator.

```
new_pop <- dnipop[names(dnipop) != 'rate']
```